# Return JsonArray with Request.CreateResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I build a ASP.NET Web Api. 
Now, i have update the project to MVC 4 RC, but the dynamic object is not working as expected anymore.

I have this:

```
var Arr = new JsonArray();

foreach (var Post in Coll)
{
    dynamic Item = new JsonObject();
    Item.Header = Post.Header;
    Item.Body = Post.Body;
    Item.Language = Post.Language;
    Arr.Add(Item);
}

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Arr);
```

The result i get from this is (In the browser):

```
[{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]},{"Header":[],"Body":[],"Language":[]}]
```

In the debugg i get this: (The object Arr)

```
{[{"Header":"All distances","Body":"All distances are ","Language":"EN"},{"Header":...
```

Why is it different?

(Coll is a List of objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it

> return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Arr.ToArray());

It is only a guess, if you can see it in the debugging then probably you force the calculating the object when you add to the watch list and the watcher displays it. And then .ToArray() should also help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess u didn't parse Arr to json data at client side.
try this in client side ajax method:

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
```

result is the value return from server.
and u can get each object of array as below:

```
        $(obj).each(function () {       
      // alert($(this).attr('Header'));  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I have fixed it inserting the Content in this way:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MY_OBJECT, Formatting.Indented), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```